# DOMDocument get element attribute

Tags: php, domdocument

I use `DOMDocument` object to get some data from this:

```
<div class="prodImg">
<a href="#"><img src="some_image_src"/></a>
</div>
```

With this code:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$homepage = file_get_contents('some_src');
$doc = new DomDocument;
@$doc->loadHtml($homepage);
$xpath = new DomXpath($doc);
$div = $xpath->query('//*[@class="prodImg"]')->item(0);
```

I get the whole div container but I want to get only the image `src` attribute.

Comment: Try to change `//*[@class="prodImg` to `//*[@class="prodImg"]/img[@src]`. I hope it will works

Comment: Unfortunately, it returns object(DOMNodeList)#3 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) } (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me:

```
$div = $xpath->query('//*[@class="prodImg"]')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
var_dump($div);
```

Yields:

```
string 'some_image_src' (length=14)
```

Comment: I'm happy to see that!